# $\sum_{i=1}^{k}[\sqrt{ip}]=\frac{p^2-1}{12}$, $p$ is a prime of the form $4k+1$

Tags: calculus, number-theory, prime-numbers, summation

$\sum_{i=1}^{k}[\sqrt{ip}]=\frac{p^2-1}{12}$, $p$ is a prime of the form $4k+1$

How to prove this?